# Prove that $\lim_{a\to0+}\int_{E\times E}\frac{1}{(x-y)^2+a}dxdy=+\infty$ where $E$ is a positive measure set in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

How to prove that$$\lim_{a\to0+}\int_{E\times E}\frac{1}{(x-y)^2+a}dxdy=+\infty$$where $E$ is a Lebesgue-measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$ s.t. $m(E)>0$?

Because the set $E$ can be any mesurable set, I can't use Newton-Leibniz formula to simplify the integration. To be honest, I can't think of a place to start.

Furthermore, I guess that$$\int_{E\times E}\frac{1}{(x-y)^2}dxdy=+\infty$$
is also true under the same assupmtion. Is that true in fact?

Comment: If $E$ had an interior point, can you prove the result?

Comment: If $E$ had an interior point, it's easy to prove that $\int_{E\times E}\frac{1}{(x-y)^2}dxdy=+\infty$ by Newton-Leibniz formula. So by Fatou's lemma we can prove the proposition.

Comment: I would try to define the set of measurable $E$ such that either $E$ has zero measure or that limit is infinity, such set is likely to have nice properties, contains the null sets and all open balls, so chances are you can get the Borel sigma field.

Comment: Been a long time. If the limit of the integrand at every point on a closed set of measure>0 is $\infty$, then integral is $\infty$, right? 

If so prove that $A=\{(x,y)\in E\times E| y=x\}$ satisfies the interval criteria might suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1<sup>st</sup> Solution.** By applying a suitable translation and restriction, it suffices to assume $E \subseteq [0, 1]$. Also, monotone convergence theorem shows that

$$ \lim_{a \to 0^+} \int_{E^2} \frac{1}{(x - y)^2 + a} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = \int_{E^2} \frac{1}{(x - y)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y. $$

Hence, it suffices to investigate the integral in the right-hand side. Let $n \geq 0$ be an integer. Then

\begin{align*}
\int_{E^2} \frac{1}{(x - y)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
&\geq \sum_{k=0}^{2^n - 1} \int_{([k/2^n, (k+1)/2^n] \cap E)^2} \frac{1}{(x - y)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
&\geq \sum_{k=0}^{2^n - 1} \int_{([k/2^n, (k+1)/2^n] \cap E)^2} \frac{1}{(1/2^n)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
&= 4^n \sum_{k=0}^{2^n - 1} m([k/2^n, (k+1)/2^n] \cap E)^2 \\
&\geq 2^n \left( \sum_{k=0}^{2^n - 1} m([k/2^n, (k+1)/2^n] \cap E) \right)^2\\
&= 2^n m(E)^2.
\end{align*}

So by letting $n \to \infty$, the claim follows.

**2<sup>nd</sup> Solution.** Let $F \subseteq E$ be measurable and bounded. Also, write $a = \varepsilon^2$ for $\varepsilon > 0$. Then by Fubini's theorem,

\begin{align*}
\int_{E^2} \frac{1}{(x - y)^2 + \varepsilon^2} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
&\geq \int_{F^2} \frac{1}{(x - y)^2 + \varepsilon^2} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
&= \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{F^2} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(\varepsilon+i(x-y))t} \, \mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\varepsilon t} \operatorname{Im} \left( \int_{F^2} e^{iyt}e^{-ixt} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \right) \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\varepsilon t} \left| \int_{F} e^{iyt} \, \mathrm{d}y \right|^2 \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\varepsilon^2 s} \left| \int_{F} e^{\varepsilon iys} \, \mathrm{d}y \right|^2 \, \mathrm{d}s. \tag{$t = \varepsilon s$}
\end{align*}

So, by the Fatou's lemma,

\begin{align*}
\liminf_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} \int_{E^2} \frac{1}{(x - y)^2 + \varepsilon^2} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
&\geq \int_{0}^{\infty} \liminf_{\varepsilon \to 0^+} e^{-\varepsilon^2 s} \left| \int_{F} e^{\varepsilon iys} \, \mathrm{d}y \right|^2 \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} m(F)^2 \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= \begin{cases}
\infty, & \text{if $m(F) > 0$}, \\
0, & \text{if $m(F) = 0$}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Now by choosing $F$ large enough so that $m(F) > 0$, we are done.